# How do I dump the values of all members of a VB.Net module?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am refactoring a legacy application which uses a huge module (static class) to store it's global state in approx. 400 different member variables:

```vb
Public Module GlobalState

Public Variable1 As Single
Public Variable2 As Single
...
Public Variable400 As Single
```

How can I dump the values of all these variables to a disk on file in a human readable format (XML, JSON..., not a binary dump)?

The commonly used object loggers require an instance of the class, but in this case everything is static.

Comment: A note: Dumping the output of the intermediate window to disk with the log()-command doesn't work here too: The output stops after 100 members. Otherwise it would be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can be done with reflection:

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Private Sub Create()

    Dim list As New List(Of GlobalStateItem)

    For Each m As FieldInfo In GetType(GlobalState).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
        list.Add(New GlobalStateItem(m.Name, m.GetValue(Nothing)))
    Next

    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(List(Of GlobalStateItem)))

    Using stream As New StreamWriter("path")
        serializer.Serialize(stream, list)
    End Using

End Sub

<Serializable()>
Public Structure GlobalStateItem
    Public Sub New(name As String, value As Object)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.Value = value
    End Sub
    Public Name As String
    Public Value As Object
End Structure

Public Module GlobalState
    Public Variable1 As Single = 1.0!
    Public Variable2 As Single = 2.0!
    Public Variable400 As Single = 400.0!
End Module
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfGlobalStateItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <GlobalStateItem>
    <Name>Variable1</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:float">1</Value>
  </GlobalStateItem>
  <GlobalStateItem>
    <Name>Variable2</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:float">2</Value>
  </GlobalStateItem>
  <GlobalStateItem>
    <Name>Variable400</Name>
    <Value xsi:type="xsd:float">400</Value>
  </GlobalStateItem>
</ArrayOfGlobalStateItem>
```